# I am trying to change my Oracle password but get ERROR: ORA-00600

Tags: oracle

My password has expired and when I enter a new one I get the following error and my password is not changed.  What is going wrong here?

ERROR:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kpdbModAdminPasswdInRoot: not CDB],
[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

EDIT:
Oracle personal edition 12c.
I am changing the password through the SQLPlus dialogue.

Comment: tell us the Oracle version, show us the script you use to change your password

Comment: Looks like bug 16901482 in 12.1.0.1 - are you changing the password on an Oracle-supplied account, rather than a schema/user account you created? Can you patch up from the base release?

Comment: @Alex, yes I'm changing oracle supplied account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got around this by logging in thus:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

then changing password.